# How to initialize all members of an array to the same value in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In C Language int myArray[42] = { 0 }; initialises all the values of the array to 0 at the start. Is there any similar way that we can do in typescript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

> The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start
>   index to an end index with a static value.

```
var arr = new Array(30);
arr.fill(0); // Fills all elements of array with 0
```

Answer (score 6):

> In C Language int myArray[42] = { 0 }; initialises all the values of the array to 0 at the start. Is there any similar way that we can do in typescript

In JavaScript latest you can use `Array.from` :

```
Array.from({length:10}); // Array of `undefined x 10`
```

Of course you can make it something else too:

```
Array.from({length:10}).map(x=>0); // Array of `0 x 10`
```

## More

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from
- use `lib` option : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#lib-option

Comment: Intuitively, is `var arr = new Array(X).fill(0);`not smarter? can JS optimize your answer such it do not allocate mem for two arrays of length X?

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen yeah, I should use fill